How to keep listening data from websockets to have a stop option BEFORE finishing a first data processing (if needed))?
I am using websockets (FastApi + uvicorn) to send a json through it and run a custom python function whose input is that json file and returns a new json as a result. I manage to do it but this function lasts several hours to compute the result (see the code block below). Therefore, I would like to add an option to Stop this function execution if a "Stop" message is received from the client also using the websocket. To do so, I need to keep listening messages while my python function is still working. And, if a new message "stop" arrives, break/kill (whatever) that execution.
However, it is important to highlight that my function is not running forever until the stop action is received, like question How to avoid blocking the asyncio event loop with looping functions suggests. In my case, I want to keep listening just in case the stop message is sent from client but, otherwise, I want my function to be completed and the result must be sent to the client.
# Assume manager connection/disconnection is coded here

def my_function(data):
    #Do things that lasts several hours using data
    return result

# WebSocket endpoint
@app.websocket("/ws/socket-endpoint")
async def ws_process(websocket: WebSocket):
    # Connect WebSocket
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    
    try:
        while True:
            # Receive data from WebSocket
            data = await websocket.receive_json()
            
            # Launch function using data as input and get result

            result = my_function(data)
       
            await manager.send_personal_message(result, websocket)
    
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        # Disconnect WebSocket
        manager.disconnect(websocket)

- What I expect:
What is the easiest approach to keep listening to a Stop order to have the possibility to stop the execution of my_function() once it has started? Taking into account:

If my function ends and computes the result before a Stop order is sent, this result must be sent back to the client through the websocket
If the Stop order is sent and the function is still running, then the execution of that function must stop.
I must receive the data that is the input to my_function(data) from the client too, first of all.

Note of what I tried:

I was trying with asyncio.create_task() (also modifying to async def my_function()) to have a task that async listens and a second one that carries out the execution of my_function, but it not seems to be working in a async mode for the "websocket.receive_json()" specifically. Is there any option commonly used in this context?
Using loop running: it is not applicable to my case because my function finishes at a particular moment, it is not repeated infinitely.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice in understanding the best way to go with this in general.
